# WordPress image output as shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, image, shortcode

I'm fed up with the original approach to images WordPress gives me.

I don't want any HTML hardcoding of images in posts. I'd just like to have it work as pretty as a gallery does, with a  shortcode that would kindly include all the parameters from the media editor (and be editable in the same way). This way I could edit the code of all images at once via functions.php.

I also don't want a separate caption shortcode - I'd like all the description-related stuff to be included in the new shortcode.

Any ideas whether it's at all possbile and where should I start? I've looked up
`get_image_tag()` but it seems to be able to redo only the HTML, not replace it with a shortcode.

BTW I considered customizing the gallery shortcode to make it act differently with single images, but it would disable the user to change the size, alignment, etc.

I hope somebody has suggestions, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, googled, etc? http://codex.wordpress.org/ is an extremely extensive documentation source.

Comment: In my own projects I've been using a manual shortcode for that, but my customers won't accept such a solution. Codex doesn't help me with that. Google returns only manual shortcode ideas (and I already have that). I also tried to disable the original image markup and transfer the data from the media editor to the caption shortcode, but 1. it didn't work 2. a caption shortcode is triggered only when there's description-related data provided and I want the shortcode to 'overtake' every image I insert, not just the described ones.